# Android: Google Places Autocomplete- How can I use it to fill a RecyclerView rather than a Dropdown Menu?

Tags: android, google-places-api

As you know, the Google Places API allows you to type into a search box and get suggested addresses in a dropdown menu.

In most examples, I've seen people use the Google Places API with an AutoCompleteTextView so that it will display autocomplete suggestions in a dropdown. What I actually want is for the suggestions to fill in a RecyclerView. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I found this sample code, hope it will help you to I am just exploring [samplecode](https://github.com/doomtrooper/GoogleAutoCompleteWithRecyclerView/tree/master/sample/app/src/main/java/com/razor/googleplacesautocompletesample/adapters)

Answer (score 0):

you can use GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions then display those results anyway you wish (ie, in your recyclerview)

see https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically for instructions